# react router v6 breadcrumbs routing with multiple params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, react-router, breadcrumbs

Ok, so I have the following breadcrumbs script which generates the breadcrumbs for my React app.  Everything works ok until I add a second param as shown below.
The actual routing works ok, its just the breadcrumbs display.

Im using react & react-router-dom v6.4.1

throws 'key' error

```
/Sites/SiteDashboard/${this.props.match.params.id}/SiteDevices/EditDevice/${row.id}
```

Breadcrumb

```
/Sites/SiteDashboard/:id/SiteDevices/EditDevice/:deviceid
```

single params works ok

```
'/Sites/SiteDashboard/:id': params => params.id,
```

have tryed this, same error

```
'/SiteDevices/:deviceid': params => params.deviceid,
```

with 2 params I get the error as shown in comments below...

I need advice on how to use the 2 params in my route without getting this 'key' error on second param. Thanks.

```
import React from 'react';
import Route from 'route-parser';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

const isFunction = value => typeof value === 'function';
const getPathTokens = pathname => {
  const paths = ['/'];

  if (pathname === '/') return paths;

  pathname.split('/').reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const currPath = `${prev}/${curr}`;
    paths.push(currPath);
    return currPath;
  });

  return paths;
};

function getRouteMatch(routes, path) {
  return Object.keys(routes)
    .map(key => {
      const params = new Route(key).match(path);
      return {
        didMatch: params !== false,
        params,
        key
      };
    })
    .filter(item => item.didMatch)[0];
}

function getBreadcrumbs({ routes, match, location }) {
  const pathTokens = getPathTokens(location.pathname);
  return pathTokens.map((path, i) => {
    const routeMatch = getRouteMatch(routes, path);
    ///////////second params error
    ///////////Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
    const routeValue = routes[routeMatch.key];
    const name = isFunction(routeValue)
      ? routeValue(routeMatch.params)
      : routeValue;
    return { name, path };  
  });
}

function Breadcrumbs({ routes, match, location }) {
  const breadcrumbs = getBreadcrumbs({ routes, match, location });

  return (
    <div>
      {' '}
      {breadcrumbs.map((breadcrumb, i) =>
        <span key={breadcrumb.path}>
          <Link to={breadcrumb.path}>
            {breadcrumb.name}
          </Link>
          {i < breadcrumbs.length - 1 ?  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'caret-right']} />  : ''}
        </span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(Breadcrumbs);
```

Comment: Do you know if `getRouteMatch` ever returns more than 1 result? You're making an assumption that the first match is always the correct one, so that might be a good place to start. If you are getting more than 1 match, you may be able to just switch the order of your routes so that your more specific routes come before your less specific routes.

Comment: In any case, the README for the `route-parser` module has an example with multiple parameters (`/users/:id/comments/:comment/rating/:rating`)

Comment: @Wex thanks. my routing is done like this             {
                ...EditDevice,
                path:'/Sites/SiteDashboard/:id/SiteDevices/EditDevice/:deviceid',
                exact: true
            }, which works fine. The breadcrumbs script is not my own so not sure how to change this.